MariaDB NO SSL Cipher
Trying to troubleshoot why Im not able to connect my client using SSL
I noticed that SSL cipher is absent but both OPENSSL and HAVE_SSL are YES. Could anyone tell me how to troubleshoot this ?
Im not getting any error in logs
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ssl%';
+---------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name       | Value                      |
+---------------------+----------------------------+
| have_openssl        | YES                        |
| have_ssl            | YES                        |
| ssl_ca              | /etc/certs/ca-cert.pem     |
| ssl_capath          |                            |
| ssl_cert            | /etc/certs/server-cert.pem |
| ssl_cipher          |                            |
| ssl_crl             |                            |
| ssl_crlpath         |                            |
| ssl_key             | /etc/certs/server-key.pem  |
| version_ssl_library | OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022  |
+---------------------+----------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.002 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> \s
--------------
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.9.2-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (aarch64) using  EditLine wrapper

Connection id:      15
Current database:
Current user:       root@localhost
SSL:            Cipher in use is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server:         MariaDB
Server version:     10.9.2-MariaDB-1:10.9.2+maria~ubu2204 mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version:   10
Connection:     Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    latin1
Conn.  characterset:    latin1
UNIX socket:        /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:         1 hour 33 min 32 sec


Look at the \s output on the MariaDB client.

@danblack added the output to the question

so it shows in status but not in variables? normal ?

Yep, status ssl_cipher (aka show status like 'ssl_cipher') vs the global permitted ssl_ciphers as a system variable.
